# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo: Binary XML file line #10 Error

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I wanna develop **NavigationDrawer** with Android-Studio.
So, When I add **NavigationView**(activity_main.xml), it gets on Error.

When I add only Toolbar & NavigationView Code in xml, it has no problem,
but, look at the **activity_main.xml**. It has ViewPager, DotsIndicator, BottomNavigationView..

[Hamburger Button on Toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78Ga0.png)

**Logcat:**

```
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 17929
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10 in com.example.myapplication:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #10 in com.example.myapplication:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10 in com.example.myapplication:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #10 in com.example.myapplication:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10 in com.example.myapplication:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:854)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1006)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:961)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1123)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:682)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:534)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:481)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:696)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:170)
        at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:50)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
E/AndroidRuntime: Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #27 in com.example.myapplication:layout/nav_header_main: Binary XML file line #27 in com.example.myapplication:layout/nav_header_main: Error inflating class TextView
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #27 in com.example.myapplication:layout/nav_header_main: Error inflating class TextView
    Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert value at index 2 to dimension: type=0x1
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(TypedArray.java:786)
        at android.widget.TextView.readTextAppearance(TextView.java:3971)
        at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:1064)
        at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:968)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:100)
        at com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView.<init>(MaterialTextView.java:93)
        at com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView.<init>(MaterialTextView.java:88)
        at com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView.<init>(MaterialTextView.java:83)
        at com.google.android.material.theme.MaterialComponentsViewInflater.createTextView(MaterialComponentsViewInflater.java:61)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:115)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1551)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1602)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1061)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:997)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:961)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1123)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1126)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:682)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:534)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.inflateHeaderView(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:222)
        at com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView.inflateHeaderView(NavigationView.java:387)
        at com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:241)
        at com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:122)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:854)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1006)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:961)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1123)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:682)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:534)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:481)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:696)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:170)
        at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:50)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    // Toolbar
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private NavigationView navigationView;

    // ViewPager & DotsIndicator 
    private ViewPager2 viewPager2;
    private DotsIndicator dotsIndicator;
    private ArrayList<DataPage> list;

    // BottomNavigationView
    private BottomNavigationView bottomNav;
    private FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    private SearchPage fragmentSearch = new SearchPage();
    private HomePage fragmentHome = new HomePage();
    private CafePage fragmentCafe = new CafePage();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // BottomNavigation
        bottomNav = findViewById(R.id.navigationView);
        bottomNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new ItemSelectedListener());

        this.InitializeLayout(); // Toolbar

        this.viewpage(); // viewPager

        //FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        //transaction.replace(R.id.frameLayout, fragmentSearch).commitAllowingStateLoss();

    }

    // Toolbar
    private void InitializeLayout() {
        //toolBar를 통해 App Bar 생성
        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false); 
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);  
        actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_reorder_white_24dp);  

    
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        //return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        int id = item.getItemId();
        switch (id) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "메뉴 버튼 클릭됨", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void viewpage(){
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new DataPage(R.drawable.sample_1, "Starbucks", 4900));
        list.add(new DataPage(R.drawable.sample_2, "Twosome Place", 4100));
        list.add(new DataPage(R.drawable.sample_3, "EDIYA", 3000));
        list.add(new DataPage(R.drawable.sample_3, "EDIYA", 3000));
        list.add(new DataPage(R.drawable.sample_3, "EDIYA", 3000));
        list.add(new DataPage(R.drawable.sample_3, "EDIYA", 3000));
        list.add(new DataPage(R.drawable.sample_3, "EDIYA", 3000));
        list.add(new DataPage(R.drawable.sample_3, "EDIYA", 3000));
        list.add(new DataPage(R.drawable.sample_3, "EDIYA", 3000));
        list.add(new DataPage(R.drawable.sample_3, "EDIYA", 3000));

        viewPager2 = findViewById(R.id.viewPager2);
        viewPager2.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapter(list));

        dotsIndicator = findViewById(R.id.dots_indicator);
        dotsIndicator.setViewPager2(viewPager2);
    }

    
    class ItemSelectedListener implements BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {

            FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.searchItem:
                    transaction.replace(R.id.frameLayout, fragmentSearch).commitAllowingStateLoss();
                    break;
                case R.id.homeItem:
                    transaction.replace(R.id.frameLayout, fragmentHome).commitAllowingStateLoss();
                    break;
                case R.id.cafeItem:
                    transaction.replace(R.id.frameLayout, fragmentCafe).commitAllowingStateLoss();
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <!-- @@@@@ When I add this tag, error @@@@@@-->
    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar_white"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
        app:itemTextAppearance="@style/text_size">
    </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>
    <!-- @@@@@ When I add this tag, error @@@@@@-->
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/cfb"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="500dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            android:background="@color/cfb"
            tools:context=".MainActivity">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TitleText2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/title2"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/viewPager2"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/refreshButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:background="@color/cfb"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/viewPager2"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/TitleText2"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/refresh_111075__2_" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/refreshText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/refresh"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/TitleText2"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/filterButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="28dp"
                android:background="@color/cfb"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/dots_indicator"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/filter"
                 />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/filterText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
                android:text="@string/filter"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/filterButton" />

            <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
                android:id="@+id/viewPager2"
                android:layout_width="270dp"
                android:layout_height="270dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="130dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.3" />

            <com.tbuonomo.viewpagerdotsindicator.DotsIndicator
                android:id="@+id/dots_indicator"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
                app:dotsColor="@color/white"
                app:dotsCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:dotsSize="14dp"
                app:dotsSpacing="4dp"
                app:dotsWidthFactor="2.5"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/viewPager2"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:progressMode="true"
                app:selectedDotColor="@color/black" />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/cafebot" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context=".MainActivity">
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/navigationView"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

            <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
                android:id="@+id/navigationView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**layout/nav_header_main:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/borderline"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/nav_header_desc"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/cafe_bot" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="@dimen/nav_header_title"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:text="@string/nav_header_menu" />
    </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar_white"
        android:gravity="left|center"
        android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="@dimen/nav_header_subtitle"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:text="카테고리" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Looking at your last stack trace, I think there is some issue with your layout of @layout/nav_header_main, can you also post the XML for @layout/nav_header_main?

Comment: I edited! can you check my code?

Comment: can you check if the dimension value in dimens.xml for the textviews in layout/nav_header_main is proper or not?

Comment: can you also paste the dimens.xml values for @dimen/nav_header_title and @dimen/nav_header_subtitle?

Comment: <dimen name="nav_header_title">35sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="nav_header_subtitle">28dp</dimen>
<dimen name="menu_text_size">22dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="toolbar_title_size">25sp</dimen>
-> oh, four dimen names have red text.

Comment: what do you mean by red text? Is there is an error in your dimens.xml file? If that's the case, can you share the screenshot?

Comment: I resolved this problem! 
I move the codes dimens(night) -> dimens

Comment: Thanks to Jain.
really..!!

Comment: Glad to know it helped! I have also added this as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is some error with your `dimens.xml` for the `@layout/nav_header_main` file, you can check in the file to resolve the issue.